# Checking if file exists then if not, PERL

Tags: perl

---

I'm needing help with a PERL script which i'm trying to do the following on a irc bot:

- on user command see if file exists.
- If not exists create new file then print value "1".
- if exists goto next stage.
- get the file information inside the file, which is a number.
- information + 1 then print into a new file, same name.

here is the script:

```
        my ($who,$channel,$message) = @_;
my @things = split(' ', $message);
            my @args = @things[1..$#things];
```

---

```
        if ($message =~ /^&cookie/i && @args[0..$#args]) {

    if ( -s '@args[0..$#args].txt') { $varr = 1; goto varrr;
    } else {
    open (USER, ">", "@args[0..$#args].txt") or die "failed: $!";
    my $sum = 1;
    print USER "$sum";
    close (USER);
    }
       varrr:
       if ($varr == 1) {
    open (USER, "<@args[0..$#args].txt");
    while (my $use = <USER>) {
    my $sum = 1;
    my $newuse = ($use + $sum);

    close (USER);

    open (USER, ">@args[0..$#args].txt");
    my $usee = $use + 1;
    print USER "$newuse\n";
    close (USER);
    print $sock "PRIVMSG $channel :You have given @args[0..$#args] a cookie! \n";
    $varr = 0;
    }
    }
    }
    elsif ($message =~ /^&cookie/i) {
    print $sock "PRIVMSG $channel :Invalid parameter, use &cookie [name]. \n";
    }
```

---

edit:

fixed, goto had to remain, thank you guys :)

[edit]

D: I must of had a file called what I tested it on, if the file doesn't exist it now no longer will create the file, now what? I've only had 3 days experience with perl.

also tried:

```
        if ($message =~ /^&cookie/i && @args[0..$#args]) {

unless ( -s '@args[0..$#args].txt') { $varr = 1;
} else {
open (USER, ">", "@args[0..$#args].txt") or die "failed: $!";
my $sum = 1;
print USER "$sum";
close (USER);
}
   varrr:
   if ($varr == 1) {
open (USER, "<@args[0..$#args].txt");
while (my $use = <USER>) {
my $sum = 1;
my $newuse = ($use + $sum);

close (USER);

open (USER, ">@args[0..$#args].txt");
my $usee = $use + 1;
print USER "$newuse\n";
close (USER);
print $sock "PRIVMSG $channel :You have given @args[0..$#args] a cookie! \n";
$varr = 0;
}
}
}
```

Comment: And what about this script doesn't work?

Comment: `goto` is a way to confusion. Whipe `goto` out and think about your code again. You could use `unless ( -s ... ) { util code here }` instead of `if ( -s ... ) { dummy } else { util code there }`

Comment: Thank you, just had to change 'if' to 'unless' as you said but goto and else had to remain.

Comment: No, the `goto` doesn't have to remain. In fact, there's a mathematical theorem proving that any program using `goto` can be transformed into a `goto`-less program using `if` and loops. Sometimes `goto` can be the best solution -- but your program is not one of those cases.

Comment: Sadly I must of had a file named what I tested the command on, it won't create a file if it doesn't exist like it's suppose to.

Answer (score 1):

you're trying to use string interpolation in the first condition `'@args[0..$#args].txt'`. perl only interpolates in double quotes or when using `qw//`. This means you are checking for the existence of a file called `@args[0..$#args].txt` not what the value of args is. `@args[0..$#args]` is an array slice which will be joined with a space when string infield. This can cause issues on some file systems.

Also it is probably better to use -e rather than -s to check for file existance as on some file systems it is possable to have a 0 length file. 
The $varr varriable is unnecessary as you can move the the code from the second conditional to the first with no change in function.